# Getting error Unable to activate appium_lib-8.0.2, because selenium-webdriver-3.0.0 conflicts with selenium-webdriver (~> 2.49)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am getting this error after installing appium_lib and selenium-webdriver

```
Unable to activate appium_lib-8.0.2, because selenium-webdriver-3.0.0 conflicts with selenium-webdriver (~> 2.49) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Below is the full stacktrace:

```
Unable to activate appium_lib-8.0.2, because selenium-webdriver-3.0.0 conflicts with selenium-webdriver (~> 2.49) (Gem::LoadError)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2007:in `raise_if_conflicts'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1176:in `activate'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:186:in `rescue in try_activate'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:183:in `try_activate'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
/Users/Anshul/Documents/Anshul/BBCStore/Automation/features/support/env.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:253:in `load_step_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:61:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have an older version of `selenium-webdriver` installed as well?

Comment: try run this command "gem list" and post result here, this because you have older and new version of selenium. your selenium command might conflict with both versions

Comment: here are the gems installed on my computer:
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

appium_lib (8.0.2)
awesome_print (1.7.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.13.4)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
childprocess (0.5.9)
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
domain_name (0.5.20160826)
ffi (1.9.14)
gherkin (4.0.0)
git (1.3.0)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.3, 1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.12.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)

Comment: netrc (0.11.0)
nokogiri (1.6.8.1, 1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rest-client (2.0.0)
rspec (3.5.0)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
ruby (0.1.0)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.0.0, 2.53.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
tomlrb (1.2.3)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
websocket (1.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that appium_lib-8.0.2 does not support selenium-webdriver-3.0.0 yet.

This issue on appium addresses that:
https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/issues/382

For now, you should be able to `gem uninstall selenium-webdriver` and get rid of version 3.0.0 unless there are particular reasons that you need that version.